# UK Layout foldable bluetooth keyboard with touchpad

Tags: keyboards, bluetooth, portable

I'm looking for a foldable bluetooth keyboard and touchpad combination to use with my Steamdeck.  Must haves:

- UK layout (with <kbd>\</kbd> between left shift and <kbd>z</kbd> and a large <kbd>Return</kbd> key)
- Staggered keys over the foldlines - so the keys are in the usual positions without a vertical split
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the bottom left, not a <kbd>fn</kbd> key
- Separate row for <kbd>Esc</kbd> and F keys, with them pressable without having to use <kbd>fn</kbd> (though happy if there's a function lock to either toggle to/from F keys and other functionality)

Nice to have also would be kick stands to raise the back slightly, but not essential.

As examples, [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/ProtoArc-Bluetooth-Foldable-Keyboard-Full-Size/dp/B0BCGFF3X2/) would be ok if it had a touchpad instead of numeric keyboard.  [This one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0CCDPMGXT/) would be ok if it weren't for the misplaced <kbd>\</kbd> which then also undersizes the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.